# What does "^" mean in node.js dependency list?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, bower

I just updated my dependencies and it automatically put the "^" symbol in front. What does it mean? There is nothing in the documentation about it.

Example

> "bower": "^1.2.8",

I could also find it in some of the npm commits https://github.com/npm/npm/commit/ce662561ca0a7b154a7e6058a6a2428b49bd7266
https://www.npmjs.org/doc/json.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's part of the syntax for semver.

From https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/semver.html

> `^1.2.3` := `>=1.2.3-0 <2.0.0-0` "Compatible with 1.2.3". When using caret
>   operators, anything from the specified version (including prerelease)
>   will be supported up to, but not including, the next major version (or
>   its prereleases).

In your case, it means the project has a dependency on bower 1.2.8, but should continue to work until bower 2.0.0.